# How to compute the correlations of extra features with respect to the principal components

Tags: pca, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with 4 features and n observations. I have done a Principal Components Analysis using only 3 features. Now I need to find the correlation between the extra feature and the principal components that I already have. How can I do this? I'm more interested in the mathematical explanation than in the python code.

````py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import datasets

# load iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris(as_frame=True)

# Select the first 3 features
data = iris.data.iloc[:, 0:3]

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(data)
normalized_data = scaler.transform(data)
y = iris.target

# apply PCA
pca = PCA()
pca_transformed = pca.fit_transform(normalized_data)
```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "find the correlation between the extra feature and the principal components that I already have"? Do you mean something like "I have 150 flowers, each flower has a PCA_1 value, and I want to find how these values correlate with the fourth feature of these flowers"? If so, then something like `np.corrcoef(pca_transformed[:,i], iris.data.iloc[:,3])` for PCA_`i+1`?

Comment: ... that is, a PC is just another variable constructed out of your variables.  To find its correlation with any variable you just ... calculate the correlation.